# Пытаюсь написать игру шахматы, появилась проблема с вводом координат хода. Ввод осуществляется в формате e2 e4. Сама доска представлена массивом

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Как можно связать индексы массива и формат ввода `e2 e4`? Например мне нужно выполнить ход с позиции `e2`, которой соответствуют индексы массива `[7][5]`, на `e4` (`[5][5]`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

string board[8][8];
string data;
std::string
PAWN_WHITE = "pw", ROOK_WHITE = "Rw", KNIGHT_WHITE = "Nw", BISHOP_WHITE = "Bw", QUEEN_WHITE = "Qw", KING_WHITE = "Kw",
PAWN_BLACK = "pb", ROOK_BLACK = "Rb", KNIGHT_BLACK = "Nb", BISHOP_BLACK = "Bb", QUEEN_BLACK = "Qb", KING_BLACK = "kb";

void BoardCount()
{
   char num = 'A';
   int hod = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
       {
           if (i < 2) board[i][j] = PAWN_WHITE;
           if (i > 5) board[i][j] = PAWN_BLACK;
           if (i > 1 && i < 6) board[i][j] = "  ";
       }
   }
   board[0][0] = ROOK_WHITE;
   board[0][1] = KNIGHT_WHITE;
   board[0][2] = BISHOP_WHITE;
   board[0][3] = QUEEN_WHITE;
   board[0][4] = KING_WHITE;
   board[0][5] = BISHOP_WHITE;
   board[0][6] = KNIGHT_WHITE;
   board[0][7] = ROOK_WHITE;
   board[7][0] = ROOK_BLACK;
   board[7][1] = KNIGHT_BLACK;
   board[7][2] = BISHOP_BLACK;
   board[7][3] = KING_BLACK;
   board[7][4] = QUEEN_BLACK;
   board[7][5] = BISHOP_BLACK;
   board[7][6] = KNIGHT_BLACK;
   board[7][7] = ROOK_BLACK;
   cout << endl;
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   {
       cout << "\t" << 8 - i;
       for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
       {
           cout << "|" << board[i][j] << "|";
       }
       cout << endl;
   }
   cout << "\t";
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   {
       cout << "   " << num;
       ++num;
   }
   cout << endl << endl << "Введите ход в фомате: e2 e4" << endl;
   
   if (((hod % 2 == 0) & (hod > 0)) | (hod == 1)) 
   {
       cout << endl << "Чёрные ходят: "; 
   }
   else 
   {
       cout << endl << "Белые ходят: ";
   }
}

void ShessHod()
{
   string coord;
   getline(cin, coord);

}

int main()
{
   setlocale(0, "Russian");
   BoardCount();
   ShessHod();
   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿Ну и в чем затруднение? Две буквы - переводите каждую в целое число, получите координаты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

координаты текущего местоположения - `board[coord[0]-'a'][coord[1]-'0']`, координаты стрыбка - `board[coord[3]-'a'][coord[4]-'0']`

#### Дополнение

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    cout << "\t" << i; // вот так
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        cout << "|" << board[i][j] << "|";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

 // ход
 if (board[coord[1] - '0'][coord[0] - 'a'] == PAWN_BLACK)
 {
     board[coord[4] - '0'][coord[3] - 'a'] = PAWN_BLACK;
 }
```

### Для автора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Каждый ход вводится с клавиатуры. Планировал сделать ввод строки, к примеру b2 b4. Эту строку разбить на две по пробелу. В итоге должен получиться массив b2; b4. Думал сделать это через split, но нет. В итоге не понимаю, как это всё можно реализовать

Comment: я так понял что b2 - координата фигуры которая будет перемещена, а b4 - куда она стрыбнет?

Comment: Да, b2 и b4 это координаты фигур. На b2 стоит PAWN_BLACK, в b4 записан пробел. И по итогу нужно поменять их местами

Comment: собственно таким способом который написан в ответе можно преобразовать текстовые координаты в числовые

Comment: все правильно преобразовивает(я проверял), правда что то не ладное с шахматним полем. Не хочет делать ход...Заметили?

Comment: Да, ход не совершается, но пока не понял в чем проблема

Comment: Готов Вам помочь. Ждите

Comment: решил!!! смотрите ответ

Comment: если я вам помог - жмякните стрелочку вверх на ответ!)))

Comment: просто сделайте чтоб цифры на поле в другом порядке были. Также, если будете проверять текущую фигуру то используйте `board[coord[1] - '0'][coord[0] - 'a']`.  `board[coord[4] - '0'][coord[3] - 'a']` - местоположение стрибка.

Comment: А если в самом начале обозначить индексы? Или это плохая идея?
std::string
board[1][1] = { "a8" }, board[1][2] = { "b8" }, board[1][3] = { "c8" }, board[1][4] = { "d8" }, board[1][5] = { "e8" }, board[1][6] = { "f8" }, board[1][7] = { "g8" }, board[1][8] = { "h8" },
board[2][1] = { "a7" }, board[2][2] = { "b7" }, board[2][3] = { "c7" }, board[2][4] = { "d7" }, board[2][5] = { "e7" }, board[2][6] = { "f7" }, board[2][7] = { "g7" }, board[2][8] = { "h7" },
board[3][1] = { "a6" }, board[3][2] = { "b6" } ну и т.д."

Comment: немного не понял суть вопроса

Comment: Я про то, что имеет ли место быть такая реализация?

Comment: можно и в самом начале( так даже визуально понятней)

Comment: смотрите в ответе. Так даже лучше ибо сразу видно шахматное поле))

Comment: еще вопросы есть?

Comment: Если вы считаете, что я вам помог - не забудьте меня отблагодарить, нажав на галочку!

Comment: Спасибо большое! Поставил

Comment: Служу StackOvefrlow!

Comment: если вам не сложно, нажмите на стрелочку вверх, а то так обидно(

Comment: Я попытался поставить, выдаёт такое: Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.

Comment: вам не хватает 2 балов. Ну когда их достанете, тогда поставите палочку вверх=)

Comment: Хорошо, договорились)

Comment: О, уже можете! Буду благодарен! Может еще вопросы?

Comment: Поставил! Спасибо, вопросов больше нет =)